# Target all that has property of 'required' except checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a 'span' after any element that has a 'required' property except for the 'checkboxes' but seems don't work on 'checkboxes' (checkbox still have span, checkbox must be excluded or not included). Any ideas, help, clues, suggestions, recommendations? Below is my snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //add required indicator to all input, select and etc. that has property of required.
  $(':required:not([name="checkbox"])').after('<span style="color:red;font-size:11px;clear:both;float:none;margin: 2px 0px 5px 0px;">This field is required</span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" required />
<br>
<input type="text" required />
<br>
<input type="text" required />
<br>
<input type="checkbox" required />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **`:required` is not a valid pseudo-selector, use [`[required]`](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)**
2. `checkbox` is `type` not `name`. The selector `[name="checkbox"]` will select all the elements having `name` attribute value as `checkbox`.

Instead of

```
$(':required:not([name="checkbox"])')
```

Use

```
$('[required]:not([type="checkbox"])')
   ^        ^      ^^^^
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //add required indicator to all input, select and etc. that has property of required.
  $('[required]:not([type="checkbox"])').after('<span style="color:red;font-size:11px;clear:both;float:none;margin: 2px 0px 5px 0px;">This field is required</span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" required />
<br>
<input type="text" required />
<br>
<input type="text" required />
<br>
<input type="checkbox" required />
```

You can also use [`:checkbox`](https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selector:

```
$('[required]:not(":checkbox")')
```

```js
$('[required]:not(":checkbox")').after('<span style="color:red;font-size:11px;clear:both;float:none;margin: 2px 0px 5px 0px;">This field is required</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" required />
<br>
<input type="text" required />
<br>
<input type="text" required />
<br>
<input type="checkbox" required />
```

Comment: nice but how about if i want to exclude both checkbox and radio type input?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using CSS2/3 only if you like to:

```
<style>
input span {
    display: none;
}

input.required:not([type="checkbox"]) + span {
    display:block;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    content: "required!";
}
</style>

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked"     class="required" />
<span></span>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="text" value="" class="required" />
<span></span>
</div>
```

What we're doing is setting spans to be hidden, but if an input has the class required and it is not a checkbox, then the span displays. You can do other sorts of tricks with the span using ::after and ::before. The **+** in CSS is the adjacent selector. We need to add the spans because ::before and ::after selectors for input[type=text] don't work, whereas it works for some of the other input fields.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp

JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wu4cdrxz/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[required]:not([type="checkbox"])')
```

- There is no `:required` pseudo selector
- You should use `[type="checkbox"]` (not `[name="checkbox"]`) because *checkbox* is a value of the attribute `type`